# a tags copying themselves while using scrollto in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollto

I am using .scrollTo to achieve the single page navigation effect. Everything with the code seems to be functioning properly until I return back up the page. I see my navigation copied multiple times in each anchors corresponding div.

---

```
$(function(){

    $("#navigation a").click(function(e){

    event.preventDefault();

    $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash,this.hash); 

    });
});
```

---

The issue only seems to happen in chrome.

I have tested in safari and it works perfectly fine.

Firefox does not have the copying issue, but locates to the corresponding div without animation.

Here is the URL : http://cfitzgerald7.mydevryportfolio.com/weresoart/index.html

Any ideas would be very much appreciated! Thank you..

Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JviRH.jpg

Comment: I don't see this happening in Chrome on my machine.  Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I have tried it out on a chromebook and no issues at all. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an issue with the number of javascript functions that you are running at once.  If you run too many js functions simultaneously with multiple different listener events, it will sometimes skip a function or not complete.

So, you will notice when your image slider changes and you scroll, the "a" tag seems to replicate.

Optimize you javascript.

Comment: I had a feeling that this was the issue. Thank you for the response!